# How Can I add(prepend) an image when I clicked the dynamic element

Tags: jquery

I want to prepend an image.When I clicked  element(this)

and my items becoming dynamic..

How can I do that? Sorry about my english

Comment: You need (at least try) to explain better and add code. E.g. what is `element(this)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
jQuery('#idOfElement').live('click' ,function() {
          jQuery(this).prepend('<img src="">');
});
```

> live: Attach a handler to the event
>   for all elements which match the
>   current selector, now and in the
>   future.